# e.preventDefault not working on live() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everything about this script works just fine but except for the `e.PreventDefault();` I've tried everything but nothing seems to work. I can't use `.click()` handler in this script because it is dynamically called, otherwise I would try that instead.

JS

```
<script>
$('#vote_up').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("votes.php", {
        vote: "1",
        item_id: "$item_id",
        type: "$type"
    }, function(data) {
        $('#vote_count').empty().append(data);
    });
});
$('#vote_down').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("votes.php", {
        vote: "-1",
        item_id: "$item_id",
        type: "$type"
    }, function(data) {
        $('#vote_count').empty().append(data);
    });
});
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="vote_box">
    <a href="#" id="vote_up">▲</a>
    <span id="vote_count">$count</span>
    <a href="#" id="vote_down">▼</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the prevent default is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/utmXa/ If you change them to real links, do they get followed?

Comment: so what's happening when you click the link? you get the # in the URL?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/kJ5bC/ (@Esailija: Note that you cannot load Google in an iframe anyway, I tried ;)).

Comment: What server-side language are you using, by the way?

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Im using PHP and I get a page load when it gets called, but the rest of the functionality (posting data, etc...) works just fine.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah I use the `X-Frame-Options` header as well (more robust than frame buster buster busters lol) but if the link were to be followed, it would throw error in chrome console :P

Comment: @Thomas: How can a page be loaded if the links don't link to any page?

Comment: Well the href="#" would not cause a page load, so I think the problem lays else where. I dunno about $.post so I could wrong to assume it does a page load when called... after you click the link, do you see # in the URL? If you see the # then preventDefault did not work.

Comment: Yeah, I see the '#'... I think the server may have been responding with HTML somewhere in the data.

Comment: In what browser(s) is this not working? What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior in those browsers?

Comment: you can try it first by removing the $.post part and see if it works correctly if it does you know it is the post part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return `false` wich will also prevent some other events that occur when your event has been fired.

```
$('#vote_up').live('click', function(e) {

$.post("votes.php", {
    vote: "1",
    item_id: "$item_id",
    type: "$type"
}, function(data) {
    $('#vote_count').empty().append(data);
});

return false;

});
```

Comment: Someone on stack has told me to neevr use return false and use preventDefault(0, I forgot why though...

Comment: Well someone here also told me to use this one instead of `e.preventDefault()`, I guess since `return false` it's just like you added `e.stopPropagation(); e.stopRequest();` there might be some cases wher you wouldn't want it, but in this case I think it should work fine